# Will Changing the Port of SVN Create the Need to Re-Checkout Projects?

Tags: svn, ssl, proxy, firewall

NOTE: I am aware of the SVN relocate switch, I just need to know if it will be necessary as we don't have a "test" svn server setup.

We need to change the port on which SVN runs on.  It is obvious that the scripts, clients, etc connecting to this new non-standard port will need to update their connections strings.

A concern came up that changing the port number would cause clients to think that the repository location has changed.  Now I'm sure there is a tiny use case for wanting multiple SVN servers running on the same IP with different ports but I'm hoping SVN doesn't care.

What if you want to move non-SSL SVN setup to 443?  Or if your proxy changes ports?  I'm praying the SVN Gods are on my side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the relocate switch of svn worked fine for me I only changed ip address however and not the port.

> svn switch --relocate
>   http://server/old-path
>   https://server/new-path

eclipse (subclipse) has this build in via the relocate menu in subversion view.

Just to clarify this is a client side command.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will definitely keep that in mind if it does cause a problem.  Do you know if this is in fact will be required?

Answer (score 2):

No problem, just use the [SVN switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html) with the --relocate param, or if you use TortoiseSVN, use the [Relocate](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html) command. This will update your working copy without needing to checkout the repo again.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should be fine.  I moved my repositories from one server to another using "svnadmin dump" and didn't have to have my users do anything different other than reconfig their clients to point to the new svn server.  I also have used svn and svn+ssh on the same repo to the same dir on my local machine and didn't have to re-checkout.

Note: when I loaded the repo dumps i used "svnadmin load --force-uuid" to try avoiding the problems like you said.

I realize what you are doing isn't the same as what I did, but I believe the same principles apply.

Comment: Interesting, I would have imagined this would have caused problems.  We're running SVN 1.4 if that makes a difference